# TensorFlow how do the new contrib.data.Dataset objects work?

Tags: tensorflow, training-data

In TensorFlow, the old input pipeline used a series of queues, and threads enqueueing and dequeueing elements from those queues. For example, the `string_input_producer` queue for file names, `tf.train.batch` as a queue for batching, etc.

Consequently before training, you needed to write:

```
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
```

In order to spawn and start the threads which populate all these queues.

---

I've upgraded my data input pipeline from this old model, to use the new one currently located in `tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset` to read the TFRecord files I am using to train.

I've noticed that I can remove the:

```
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
```

lines of code, and the input pipeline still runs smoothly.

**So my question is this:**

**How does the new input pipeline work under the hood? Does it not use queues at all? Or does it use them, and just start them itself? Furthermore, if it does use them, is there a way of monitoring how full they are, as the old pipeline did that automatically, and the new one doesn't?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr Queues are no longer used as it's now integrated into the TF graph. The iterator management takes place *deep* in the code.

The standard method of getting the data tensor from `tf.data.Dataset` is to call `next(dataset)`. to get the Tensor to use as input to the first layer of the network. Under the hood, this builds an object called `IteratorV2` [1]. Then, some indirection takes the call to `IteratorV2._next_internal` [2] where it branches. If not executing eagerly, it calls `gen_dataset_ops.iterator_get_next`, otherwise it calls `gen_dataset_ops.iterator_get_next_sync`. This is a file generated at build time, so we don't have it on GitHub, but in my compilation this usually calls `_pywrap_tensorflow.TFE_Py_FastPathExecute` which creates a node in the TF graph using "A `Tensor` of type `resource`".

I can't find any way to monitor what's going on under the hood. `IteratorV2` has no methods for it and `tf.data.Dataset` is way too high level for that.

Links:

1. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.14/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py#L588
2. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.14/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py#L588